# How do I make the SVG Object clickable and scroll to anchor using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

My SVG is embedded through an object tag and also has CSS3 hover animations. Trying to hyperlink the SVG with hover animation is messing with the pointer or clicking action. I didn't use the long SVG path code for code organization preference.

This JavaScript below makes it clickable but it won't go to the desired anchor # to scroll later in the page. **Do you know how to combine these two click functions?**

This is messy, I know!

HTML

```
<object id="example" type="image/svg+xml" data="/images/icon.svg"> </object>
```

Inside the SVG:

```
<a xlink:href="#top">
    <g class="whole" fill="#fff">
        <rect id="body" x="113.83" y="185.4" width="43" height="49.5" style="stroke:#f36a24;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:3px" />
        <ellipse id="head" cx="134.96" cy="165.04" rx="14.13" ry="13.92" style="stroke:#f36a24;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:3px" />
    </g>
</a>
```

//JS below

```
<script>
       (function ($) {
           $(document).ready(function () {
               $('svg a').click(function (event) {
                   alert(event.target.parentElement.tagName);
               });
           });
       })(jQuery);

</script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function () {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said click is working, in order to scroll to another anchor a one more step need to be done. Only you need to do this following code snippet when the click event.

```
$('html, body').animate({
      'scrollTop':   $('#scrollTo').offset().top
}, 2000);
```

Check this example  https://jsfiddle.net/q70jq0kt/1/

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have 5 svg icons. Each has a CSS hover animation and each one has an anchor ID that once clicked will scroll to a section further down the page. So I don't want to write an exact ID. So the jQuery can apply to all svgs, should it just say $('#') or something?

Comment: What you can do is, keep a data attribute to hold the id of the anchor that you want to scroll to. Then read that value within the on click event and scroll to that element. $('object').on('click', function () {
    var scroll = $(this).data('scroll')
       $('html, body').animate({
      'scrollTop':   $('#' + scroll).offset().top
    }, 2000);
  });If you didn't get it, please go through this sample.https://jsfiddle.net/87q5y0zx/

Comment: If it resolves your issue, why don't use cast a vote :)